Why is my file io working correctly in gfortran, nvfortran, flang, but not ifort?
I am working on a Fortran95 solution to Project Euler problem 22. I have it working correctly in the three complilers listed in the title, but for some reason the array labelled names is filled incorrectly when compiled with ifx/ifort. It's just a jumbled mess with a bunch of 1-character names and others that make no sense
Below is my solution. Note that open_data_file is from utils, and I will include it below. Some of my debug prints are not indented, as they are entirely temporary
! Project Euler Problem 22
!
! Problem:
!
! Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text file
! containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it into
! alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for each name,
! multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name
! score.
!
! For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is
! worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would
! obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.
!
! What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

module Problem0022
    use constants
    use utils
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: name_count = 5163
contains
    integer(i18t) function p0022() result(answer)
        character(len=DATA_MAX_NAME_SIZE), parameter :: file_name = "p0022_names.txt"
        character(len=DATA_MAX_NAME_SIZE), dimension(name_count) :: names
        character(len=DATA_MAX_NAME_SIZE) :: temp
        character(len=1) :: current_char
        integer(i18t) :: score
        integer :: ios, unit, i, j, k

        i = 1
        j = 1
        k = 1
        answer = 0
        names = ''
        unit = open_data_file(file_name, .true., 1)
        do
            read(unit, rec=j, IOSTAT=ios) current_char
            j = j + 1
            if (ios /= 0) then
                exit
            end if

            select case (current_char)
                case (',')
                    i = i + 1
                    k = 1
                case ('"')
                case default
                    names(i)(k:k) = current_char
                    k = k + 1
            end select
        end do
do i=1, size(names)
print *, names(i)
end do
        close(unit)
        do i = 1, size(names)
            do j = 1, size(names) - i
                if (names(j) > names(j + 1)) then
                    temp = names(j)
                    names(j) = names(j + 1)
                    names(j + 1) = temp
                end if
            end do
        end do
do i=1, size(names)
print *, names(i)
end do
        close(unit)
        do i = 1, name_count
            score = 0
            do j = 1, len_trim(names(i))
                score = score + ichar(names(i)(j:j)) - ichar('A') + 1
            end do
            answer = answer + score * i
        end do
    end function p0022
end module Problem0022

integer function open_data_file(name, direct, recl) result(unit)
        character(len=DATA_MAX_NAME_SIZE), intent(in) :: name
        logical, intent(in), optional :: direct
        integer, intent(in), optional :: recl
        integer :: ios

        unit = prev_unit + 1
        prev_unit = unit
        if (present(direct) .and. present(recl) .and. direct) then
            open(unit=unit, file=("../_data/" // name), status='old', action='read', iostat=ios, access='direct', recl=recl)
        else
            open(unit=unit, file=("../_data/" // name), status='old', action='read', iostat=ios)
        end if
        if (ios /= 0) then
            print *, "Error opening file: ../_data/" // name
            return
        end if
    end function

I tried reading in sequential mode, checking the file encoding, adjusting the type of current_character, and some degree of debug printing. Due to environment problems, I have some difficulty using gdb with Fortran specifically. I expect behavior to match that of other compilers.

Also note if (present(direct) .and. present(recl) .and. direct) is incorrect - you can not depend upon the order of evaluation of these expressions, and therefore do not know the direct is present before you evaluate it. You need to split this into first evaluating present(direct) and only if that is true evaluating direct itself.

Best would be to provide a minimal. reproducible example - it's difficult to diagnose bugs without something to test. A link to whatever Project Euler is as well would help.

You cannot just pass 1 to recl=. I recommend reading the full explanation in answer to the linked duplicate, but -assume byterecl will likely help. Also possibly -standard-semantics. However, you should never pass a magic number constant to recl=, you should always use inquire before.

Also, I recommend to use subroutines and not functions for this kind of code (e.g., opening a data file). It is much better to reserve functions for something that really mostly just computes something and returns the result as the main thing it does. It is very good to try to keep all functions pure, even if not designating them such.

You know, you are making the file read far too difficult. Just name=""; open( 10, file="0022_names.txt" ); read( 10, *, iostat=io ) names will work for that input file. You can find the number of names actually read simply by checking for the first one with a blank as the first character.

Also, if you abandon the ancient Fortran 95 and allow at least Fortran 2003, you can use access="stream" to read individual bytes portably. It is designed to match the way C works with files.
